# Changing GUI directly from Qthread PyQt 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

Hi i have send to my Thread worker link to GUI and update GUI info directly from  QThread. Like here:

```
class Worker(QThread):
  def __init__(self, ui):
    QThread.__init__(self)
    self.running = False
    self.ui = ui

  def run(self):
    self.running = True
    while self.running:
        info = self.check_info()
        rows = len(info)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(rows)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6) 
        ...
```

In main `QMainWindow` i just add

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    .......
    self.myworker = Worker(self.ui)
    .....
```

Is such solution very bad in PyQt5? I am new in PyQt. Thx. If my solution is bad plz help me to fix it.

Comment: You should not update the GUI in another thread other than the main thread, you must use signals and slots to send the information from the secondary threads to the main thread.

Comment: what is type of `info`?

Comment: May i send any info through signals for example list of dicts which i recieve by executing the thread?

Comment: `info` is list of dicts

Comment: Yes, if you can, but you need a particular syntax. Why do you need to get run check_info in another thread?

Comment: `check_info`- has to be infinitive loop till the use won't press stop button

Comment: Okay, I'll post my answer in a moment.

Comment: also may i send status bar messages from thread?

Comment: What are status bar messages?

Comment: simple str messages, example:`self.ui.statusbar.showMessage("Requesting info")`

Comment: Of course, the signal will send a string to the slot, then you can use it as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not and can not update the GUI from a secondary thread, you must do it through signals and slots:

For this we are going to create a signal through the class `pyqtSignal()`, and we will indicate the types of arguments, then we connect it to the slot that we want, as I show below:

Thread:

```
class Worker(QThread):
    list_of_dict_signals = pyqtSignal(list)
    str_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            info = self.check_info()
            self.list_of_dict_signals.emit(info)
            self.str_signal.emit("Requesting info")
```

GUI:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    .......
    self.myworker = Worker(self)
    self.myworker.list_of_dict_signals.connect(self.onDataFromThread)
    self.myworker.str_signal.connect(self.ui.statusbar.showMessage)
    self.myworker.start()

def onDataFromThread(self, info):
    rows = len(info)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(rows)
    ...
```

Comment: Thx for solution for what we are using `def  onDataFromThread`?

Comment: In this function you will receive the list of dictionaries, that is to say, every time you send the signal that sends the list of dictionaries that function will be called, there you must update the ui.tableWidget.

Comment: Big thx for answer inow i understand how signals slot work. I have marked

Comment: I recommend that you study the signals, the slots and the events. These are a primordial part of Qt and therefore of PyQt.