# python pyQT5 : create separate thread that does not block the main QTwidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I want to create a separate thread that does not freeze my application, I'm using pyQt5 and here is a simple example of my code :

```
def record(self):
    for i in range(100000000):
        t="allllaaaa"
    self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText("waiting ... ")


def threadRecord(self):
    self.textEdit.setPlaceholderText("speak now ")
    thread = Thread(target = self.record)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Basic rule of Qt, you can only update the GUI from the main thread called GUI thread, check the following link so you understand the reason: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread, also if you want to use a thread with some other Qt resource (not the GUI) it is advisable to use QThread, QThreadPoll and QRunnable.

Comment: Here is an example that I believe accomplishes what you are trying to do [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665939/6594646](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665939/6594646)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing GUI directly from Qthread PyQt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665787/changing-gui-directly-from-qthread-pyqt-5)